# Why does gnuplot complain about empty x range (and ruin the graph) when I apply missing data cutoff?

Tags: plot, graph, gnuplot

gnuplot 5.2.5 / centos7

Basically, I've configured a plot that I like but now I want to introduce a "cut off" in the lines when the data is missing. I've looked around a lot and there are easy solutions, if I only have 2 columns... However, I have a lot of columns. So, I am using a loop and can't just do `($2)`.

I've found solution to cut lines where there is no data in a loop but they don't work:

> Warning: empty x range [2018:2018], adjusting to [1997.82:2038.18]

The configuration that caused the above:

```
set datafile separator ","
set xdata time
set timefmt "%Y-%m-%d.%H:%M:%S"
set datafile missing
set ylabel "% CPU"
set xlabel "Time Point"
set grid
set xtics rotate
set key autotitle columnheader
set terminal pngcairo
set output 'graph.png'
plot for [i=2:5] "data.csv" using ($1):(column(i)) with linespoints
```

And here's my data (notice the missing value on second row, second col):

> col1,col2,col3,col4
>   2018-11-21.04:23:03,1,2,2,5
>   2018-11-21.04:24:03,,4,4,6
>   2018-11-21.04:25:03,3,6,8,7
>   2018-11-21.04:26:03,4,8,16,8

What should my plot command look like?

Update: I tried working around it with:

```
plot "data.csv" using 1:($2) with linespoints,
plot "data.csv" using 1:($3) with linespoints,
```

But it just plots the first line... This workaround is feasible for me but I don't know how to add more lines? Again, I cannot use the for [i=2:5] trick because that breaks my x range.

Comment: Instead of `($1)`,  just use `1`. Same with `($2)` etc.

Comment: Simply using `plot for [i=2:5] "data.csv" using 1:i with linespoints` works fine for me with 5.2.2, https://i.stack.imgur.com/zftPw.png